# My Code is taking too much time to finish executing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I am very weak in Mysql

I had to update the question id of an answer table according to some condition I have written following script but it takes more than 700 Seconds to execute because the data is huge,

Can any one please Help me fix this

```
function UpdateAnswer()
{
ini_set('max_execution_time', 800);
        $users= DB::select(DB::raw("select * from users where role!='admin_dd' and role!='sales_dd' "));

foreach($users as $user)
       {
         $answers= DB::select(DB::raw("select * from answers where  user_id='$user->id' "));

         foreach($answers as $answer)
                {

            $questionDetNew = '';
            $questionDetOld = DB::select(DB::raw("select * from questions where  id='$answer->question_id' "));
             if(is_array($questionDetOld))
                echo "questionDetOld true";

            foreach ($questionDetOld as $question) {
                # code...
                echo "<br/>";
                echo $question->id;
                echo $question->question_text;
                echo $user->event; echo"<br/>";


                $questionDetNew= DB::select(DB::raw("select * from questions where question_text='$question->question_text' and event='$user->event' and question_group='$question->question_group' "));

            }

            if(is_array($questionDetNew)){
            foreach ($questionDetNew as $questionx) {
                # code..
                if($questionx->id!=NULL){
                            echo "Updated<br/>";
            //DB::select(DB::raw("update answers set question_id='$questionx->id' where id='$answer->id' "));
        }
        else {
                echo "Its already existing ";
        }

            }
        }
     }
   }

}
```

**UPDATE**

I came up with this following  According to the comments provided  but still the execution time is not much difference

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 800);
        $users= DB::select(DB::raw("select * from users where role!='admin_dd' and role!='sales_dd' "));
        // $users = User::where('role','!=','admin_dd')->orWhere('role','!=','sales_dd')->orderby('name')->get();
        $answers= DB::select(DB::raw("select * from answers "));
        $questionDetOld = DB::select(DB::raw("select * from questions"));

        foreach($users as $user)
        {
            foreach ($answers as $answer) {

                if($answer->user_id==$user->id)
                {
                    foreach($questionDetOld as $question)
                    {
                        if($question->id==$answer->question_id  )
                        {

                                    echo "<br/>";
                                    echo $question->id;
                                    echo $question->question_text;
                                    echo $user->event; echo"<br/>";
                                    //$questionDetNew= DB::select(DB::raw("select * from questions where question_text='$question->question_text' and event='$user->event' and question_group='$question->question_group' "));

                                    foreach ($questionDetOld as $questionx) {
                                        if($questionx->question_text==$question->question_text && $questionx->event==$user->event && $questionx->question_group==$question->question_group)
                                        {
                                          echo "Updated<br/>";
                                        }
                                    }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It should take time due to running queries in loops its better if you construct one joined query instead of running extra queries  in loops

Comment: Your query is slow because you are running your query inside loops. Put your queries outside loop to make it faster.

Comment: you have 2 of these `# code...` so we are blind. As stated above, if you can move this into mysql, it will scream by comparison

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava updated My answer still the execution time is going more than 600 seconds I guess , Can you help me write a join query

Comment: Try implementing index on foreign ids like: question_id, user_id. See if that decrease execution time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do you have correct indexes in database?
Second, you have too much loops inside loops. On large amounts of data it can be really slow. You can optimize this script by preparing arrays, indexed by key fields. Here is an example:

```
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 800);

    $userIds = array();
    $users= DB::select(DB::raw("select * from users where role!='admin_dd' and role!='sales_dd' "));
    forach ($users as $user) {
        $userIds[] = $user->id;
    }

    $questionIds = array();
    $answers_tmp= DB::select(DB::raw("select * from answers where user_id in (".implode(',',$userIds).')'));
    foreach ($answers_tmp as $answer) {
        $answers[$answer->user_id][] = $answer;
        $questionIds[] = $answer->question_id;
    }

    $questionDetOld_tmp = DB::select(DB::raw("select * from questions where id in (".implode(',',$questionIds).')'));
    foreach ($questionDetOld_tmp as $question) {
        $questionDetOld[$question->id][] = $question;
    }

    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        if (isset($answers[$user->id]))
        {
            foreach ($answers[$user->id] as $answer)
            {
                if (isset($questionDetOld[$answer->question_id]))
                {
                    foreach($questionDetOld[$answer->question_id] as $question)
                    {
                        echo "<br/>";
                        echo $question->id;
                        echo $question->question_text;
                        echo $user->event; echo"<br/>";
                        //$questionDetNew= DB::select(DB::raw("select * from questions where question_text='$question->question_text' and event='$user->event' and question_group='$question->question_group' "));

                        foreach ($questionDetOld_tmp as $questionx)
                        {
                            if($questionx->question_text==$question->question_text && $questionx->event==$user->event && $questionx->question_group==$question->question_group)
                            {
                                echo "Updated<br/>";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am getting some offset error Maybe Some of the data is not indexed properly in the DB

Comment: Edited my response, added check for data existance.

Comment: well the execution time reduced from 10.20 min to 4.48 min , Still its a lot I will accept your answer but if you think if there is some way I can improve the performance more please let me know

Comment: I think you can select from database only those questions and answers, that you will actually use.
Edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid queries inside loops, use it like this

```
$INuserdata[] = array();
$INanswerdata[] = array();
$users= DB::select(DB::raw("select * from users where role!='admin_dd' and role!='sales_dd' "));
foreach($users as $user)
     $INuserdata[] = $user->id;

$answers= DB::select(DB::raw("select * from answers where  user_id IN (".implode(',',$INuserdata).")"));
foreach($answers as $answer)
    $INanswerdata[] = $answer->question_id;

$questionDetOld = DB::select(DB::raw("select * from questions where  id IN (".implode(',',$INanswerdata).")"));
```